# How to select an item in a QComboBox using the Tab key?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqt5, qcombobox

I have a shiny `QComboBox` that has three (3) items to select. Here's the code to create the ComboBox:

```
class TabComboBox(QComboBox):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        # Populate combobox
        self.addItems(['Dog', 'Cat', 'Bird'])
```

Here's the screenshot of the ComboBox

[image]

I want to confirm my selection using the `Tab` key aside from using the `Enter` key. So when I use the arrow keys or 
point my mouse in *Cat* and press `Tab`, the ComboBox should display *Cat*. But nothing happens when I pressed the `Tab` 
key. Only the `Enter` key enables me to select an item. I also want to use the `Tab` key. How can I do that?

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: catch the key event with Qt .. check if TAB key was pressed then write the logic. You also need to bypass TAB pressed outside your combo box, so add a check if combobox is focused

Comment: Thank you for the response @MohammadKanan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to filter the `QEvent::ShortcutOverride` event when the TAB key is pressed, and perform the logic of changing the index and hiding the popup.

```
class TabComboBox(QComboBox):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QComboBox.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        # Populate combobox
        self.addItems(['Dog', 'Cat', 'Bird'])
        self.view().installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.ShortcutOverride:
            if event.key() == Qt.Key_Tab:
                self.hidePopup()
                self.setCurrentIndex(self.view().currentIndex().row())
                return True
        return QComboBox.eventFilter(self, obj, event)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app =QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = QWidget()
    myapp.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
    myapp.layout().addWidget(TabComboBox())
    myapp.layout().addWidget(QTextEdit())
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: You nailed this one. Thank you for the detailed response!